# Entityframework - Add additional properties

Tags: sql, entity-framework, data-annotations

I have an sql that queries a table (TableA) and add additonal infos (columns) through table joins. I want then this sql to be executed by ef (DbContext.Database.SqlQuery) and the result mapped to the auto generated class (TableA) with the additional properties added in the partial class located in a seperate file.I've tried using data annotations [Column("Name")] but the new columns don't get mapped. How can i solve this?

Here's some more details:

This code works, all fields are mapped:

```
string sql = 
"SELECT ta.* FROM TableA ta
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB tb
ON ta.SomeID = tb.SomeID
WHERE tb.SomeCol > 1";

var list = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TableA>(sql).ToList();
```

This code works but additional fields are not mapped:
string sql =

```
"SELECT ta.*, tb.SomeOtherCol1, tb.SomeOtherCol2 FROM TableA ta
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB tb
ON ta.SomeID = tb.SomeID
WHERE tb.SomeCol > 1";

var list = DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TableA>(sql).ToList();
```

I've extended the partial class TableA like this.

```
public partial class TableA
{
    [Column("SomeOtherCol1")]
    public string SomeOtherCol1 { get; set; }

    [Column("SomeOtherCol2")]
    public string SomeOtherCol2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us your code.

Comment: Show your query and your class.